# select2 v4 dropdown change event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

please help me, select2 v4+ change event not working.
this is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#asal").on("change", function(){
  var asallbl = $("#asal :selected").parent().attr("label");
  if(asallbl === "Singapore"){
    $("#tujuan").find("optgroup[label='Indonesia']").show();
    $("#tujuan").find("optgroup[label='Singapore']").hide();
    $("#tujuan").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
  }else{
    $("#tujuan").find("optgroup[label='Indonesia']").hide();
    $("#tujuan").find("optgroup[label='Singapore']").show();
    $("#tujuan").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the on change event is not firing when the element with id asal is changed? What type of element is #asal?

Comment: please see my previous post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237365/how-to-change-other-country-if-i-select-one-country-in-jquery

Comment: Read [Event DOC](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events)

Comment: I've just tried Kumar code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237539/7558177 and it is working like charm. Is it possible that you're missing something?

Comment: Yeah right, it works well.
but it doesn't work if I use the library from select2